# Reshape a viewmodel to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

On client side I display data in a way customized for the view needs.

When the user saves and sends the data to the server I do NOT want to reshape the data on

client side to fit the requirements of my domain.

To reshape my ViewModel to my Model I COULD do this:

```
var periods = periodListViewModel.CellViewModels
                                 .SelectMany(c => c.Rows)
                                 .Select(
                                     p => 
                                        new Period { LessonNumber = p.LessonNumber });
```

This code must be put at a place of the correct responsibility.

These are my classes:

```
 public class SavePeriodListViewModel
    {
        public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CellViewModel> CellViewModels { get; set; }
    }

public class CellViewModel
    {
        public CellViewModel()
        {
            Rows = new List<RowViewModel>();
        }
        public List<RowViewModel> Rows { get; set; }
    }

public class RowViewModel
{
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int LessonNumber { get; set; }
}

public class LessonplannerResponse
{
        public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Period> Periods { get; set; }
}
```

All data I need for my model Period is inside the RowViewModel.

I need to reshape my SavePeriodListViewModel to the LessonplannerResponse

Of course AutMapper can handle the RowViewModel to Period mapping but my problem is not in that area.

AutoMapper is mapping not reshaping collections.

Where should I put the linq reshaping code? Or more general asked where should I put such code in asp.net mvc ?

- client side?
- controller action?

service is no option as it should not know the viewmodel.

Comment: Elist Automapper does it very well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the mapping needs to happen inside the controller. I would expect that the Controller Action is defined something like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SavePeriodListViewModel model)
{
    // transform from model to LessonplannerResponse

    // validate model

    // do something with the model and return a view
}
```

From the look that we have into your processes, it doesn't appear to be the responsibility of a service to do the transformation, nor does it appear to be the responsibility of the client side -- especially since you already ruled out the client side in your question.

Comment: Hm there are many "would" words in your statement. And your last paragraph makes me unsure whether this is a statement or a question. But I must also admit that I was somehow blind because the AutoMapper stuff is always done inside the controller action. So why the reshaping not either?! But there is one big difference between reshaping and mapping. I can reshape on clientside and send a reshaped viewmodel but I can/should not map on clientside to a domain entity. Your answer is correct in general that the mapping/reshaping should happen in the action, but for me personally  ...

Comment: - now I remembered again that I have something special to do on client side - I will very probably do the reshaping on client side from my JS viewmodel to c# viewmodel and from the viewmodel directly to the model no DTO like lessonplannerresponse anymore.

Comment: Well, that's English for you...  Since I do not know the details of your desired processes, I was simply trying to propose possible solutions to your need.  Glad that I was able to provide some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of how i do it to ViewModel you can also implement it visa verse.

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<Faq, FaqViewModel>()
                  .ForMember(x => x.Answer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Answer))
                  .ForMember(x => x.Question, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Question));

  var sourceOfModels = _repository.GetFaqListByAppId(id);
  var resultOfViewModels = Mapper.Map<List<Faq>, List<FaqViewModel>>(list.ToList());
```

This is works perfect for me.

Comment: From you sample I assume you have not understood my problem or you have not correctly read it. Of course your sample works. Its a 1:1 mapping problem and you solved it with AutoMapper. But your answer is not an answer to my question or my problem. I am not asking how to map a viewmodel to a model.

Comment: @Elisa so where do you see a problem in your case?